# WordPress translation issue with HTML enteties

Tags: php, wordpress, translation

I'm currently trying to translate a text in WordPress. The problem is that I'm trying to translate HTML characters which seems to be converted during the translation but I need them as they are in the JS I'm localizing:

```
wp_localize_script( 'main-js', 'main_object', array(
    'homepage_typed_text' => __( 'Apples &amp; Bananas', 'ewk' )
) );
```

So in the JS it needs to be `Apples &amp; Bananas` and not `Apples & Bananas`. When I copy it directly to the JS, everything works but not via the translation. Any ideas why this happens?

**Update**

I've checked the code and found this little thing here in the localize function:

```
$l10n[ $key ] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
```

So this function transforms every entity back to his original sign. Damn. So no idea how to skip this..

Comment: `html_entity_decode` only reverts one “level” of encoding. So if you make that `'Apples &amp;amp; Bananas'`, it should get you the result you want.

Comment: @misorude I've also tried this but it get's reformatted again like I described in my question.

Comment: But `html_entity_decode` gets applied only once, so this should work … Unless perhaps the translation function `__` also modifies the input value already? Can you see if it makes a difference when you pass `'Apples &amp;amp; Bananas'` as value directly, without wrapping it in `__()`?

Comment: If I'm not wrapping it into __() it don't get's translated into the different languages :) And yes, this makes no difference because the array passed in the localize get's decoded on each page load. So every time.

Comment: Well yeah duh, I meant for _testing_, to verify whether the translation function perhaps does additional decoding, or not. _“because the array passed in the localize get's decoded on each page load. So every time”_ - I don’t see what that is even supposed to have to do with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found no solution in PHP so I moved to JS:

```
main_object.homepage_typed_text.replace( /[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function ( i ) {
    return "&#" + i.charCodeAt( 0 ) + ";";
} );
```

So replaces the &, ä, ü, etc. back to his entities. If someone has a better solution, let me know it.